# Nested for loop in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm quite new to Prolog so im not sure how this can be done.

I'm trying to create a nested for loop that outputs the three variables on each line.

I'm trying to get an output that loops like the following:

SWI-Prolog

```
?- out(A, B, C).
```

```
A = 1, B = 1, C = 1 (Next)
A = 1, B = 1, C = 2 (Next)
A = 1, B = 2, C = 1 (Next)

A = 1, B = 2, C = 2 (Next)
A = 2, B = 1, C = 1 (Next)
A = 2, B = 1, C = 2 (Next)

A = 2, B = 2, C = 1 (Next)
A = 2, B = 2, C = 2 (Next)
```

it needs to have a custom range

in Python it would look like this

```
for i in range(1,3):
    for j in range(1,3):
        for k in range(1,3):
        print(i, j, k)
```

Comment: You're trying to write an imperative program in a logic language. It's a bit like asking how to use a screwdriver to hammer in a nail. You can do it, but it's not what the tool was built for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
out(A, B, C) :-
    maplist(between(1, 2), [A, B, C]).
```

Result:

```
?- out(A, B, C).
A = B, B = C, C = 1 ;
A = B, B = 1,
C = 2 ;
A = C, C = 1,
B = 2 ;
A = 1,
B = C, C = 2 ;
A = 2,
B = C, C = 1 ;
A = C, C = 2,
B = 1 ;
A = B, B = 2,
C = 1 ;
A = B, B = C, C = 2.
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the simplest programme I can think of that uses basic Prolog facts and predicates:

```
fact(1).
fact(2).

out(A,B,C) :- fact(A), fact(B), fact(C).
```

When I run that and keep asking it to go back for more, I get this:

```
?- out(A,B,C).
A = B, B = C, C = 1 ;
A = B, B = 1, C = 2 ;
A = C, C = 1, B = 2 ;
A = 1, B = C, C = 2 ;
A = 2, B = C, C = 1 ;
A = C, C = 2, B = 1 ;
A = B, B = 2, C = 1 ;
A = B, B = C, C = 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way?

```
out(A,B,C) :-
  between(1,2,A),
  between(1,2,B),
  between(1,2,C).
```

Then you can just chant the incantation

```
?- out(A,B,C), writeln([A,B,C]), fail.
```

And get

```
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
```